# Azure AD Connect powershell requirement

Tags: powershell, installation, azure

I am trying to install Azure AD Connect on my domain controller (Windows 2008 R2). During the install, I get the following error: I have dowloaded the Windows Management Framework 4.0 but it doesnt seem to help make the error go away. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted an installation of Azure AD Connect on a 2008R2 SP1 DC this weekend and ran in to this exact same error. I ended up downloading these two items:

Windows Management Framework 4.0 (which I know you stated you have already downloaded and installed):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

I also downloaded and installed .NET 4.5.1:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779

I think the trick that did it for me was installing Windows Updates and then re-installing the Windows Management Framework. That got me past the error you have, but then I got the message that .NET 4.0 was not installed.

After I installed .NET 4.5.1, I applied another round of Windows Updates.

Doing all of that resolved my issue with getting Azure AD Connect past the error message you are currently having. My issue now is that I get this message at the end of the installation:

"azure ad connect unable to install the synchronization service".

YMMV.

Comment: how did you re-install it? I get an error that the management framework is already installed when I try to install again.

Comment: Nevermind, git it working. I kicked off the installer again with an -uninstall command line switch.